# Moving Json response data into dropdown

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-change

I have the following JSON data.

I need to move all Role name into dropdown.

JSON:

```
{
"json": {
    "response": {
      "servicetype": "1",
      "functiontype": "10011",
      "statuscode": "0",
      "statusmessage": "Success",
      "data": {
        "assignedroles": [
          {
            "roleid": 162,
            "rolename": "Admin",
            "roleinformation": {
              "A": [
                {
                  "1st floor": 10
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "roleid": 163,
            "rolename": "Resident",
            "roleinformation": {
              "A": [
                {
                  "1st floor": 10
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "unassignedroles": [
          {
            "roleid": 36,
            "rolename": "Product Managers",
            "divisionlabel": "Department ",
            "subdivisionlabel": "Category",
            "roleinformation": {
              "QA": [
                {
                  "White Box Testing": 0
                }
              ]
            }
          },

          {
            "roleid": 108,
            "rolename": "Teacher",
            "divisionlabel": "Class",
            "subdivisionlabel": "Div",
            "roleinformation": ""
          },
          {
            "roleid": 115,
            "rolename": "Staff",
            "divisionlabel": "Class",
            "subdivisionlabel": "Section",
            "roleinformation": {
              "1": [
                {
                  "A": 0
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "roleid": 116,
            "rolename": "Student",
            "divisionlabel": "Class",
            "subdivisionlabel": "Section",
            "roleinformation": {
              "1": [
                {
                  "A": 0
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "roleid": 184,
            "rolename": "CANt_MANAGE_Gbase",
            "divisionlabel": "Division",
            "subdivisionlabel": "SubDivision",
            "roleinformation": {
              "Div": [
                {
                  "Sdiv": 0
                },
                {
                  "Sdiv1": 0
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "roleid": 191,
            "rolename": "Legend",
            "divisionlabel": "a",
            "subdivisionlabel": "b"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get rolename of both assigned and unassigned values from json response. I am able to do for only assignedroles, but couldn't work with moving both.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-10" for="groupz">Select Role*</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="role"
          ng-model="model.rolename"
          ng-change="GetAssignRole(model.rolename)">
    <option selected>Select Roles</option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in model.roles track by $index"
            value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
  </select>
  <div>
```

Need assistance with handling JS part of it, like how to load it in dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by concating assignedroles[] and unassignedroles[] to make single array.Is your "model.roles" is having both "assignedroles" and "unassignedroles".

If not then use `Arrat.prototype.concat() to concat.`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/y8dmed9XQiMmDLosAVnG?p=preview)

You need to combine both assigned and unassigned rule and push it in a array like this

```
app.controller('CompaniesController', ['$scope',function($scope) {
 var mData=[{
"json": {
    "response": {
      "servicetype": "1",
      "functiontype": "10011",
      "statuscode": "0",
      "statusmessage": "Success",
      "data": {
        "assignedroles": [
          {
            "roleid": 162,
            "rolename": "Admin",
            "roleinformation": {
              "A": [
                {
                  "1st floor": 10
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "roleid": 163,
            "rolename": "Resident",
            "roleinformation": {
              "A": [
                {
                  "1st floor": 10
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "unassignedroles": [
          {
            "roleid": 36,
            "rolename": "Product Managers",
            "divisionlabel": "Department ",
            "subdivisionlabel": "Category",
            "roleinformation": {
              "QA": [
                {
                  "White Box Testing": 0
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "roleid": 108,
            "rolename": "Teacher",
            "divisionlabel": "Class",
            "subdivisionlabel": "Div",
            "roleinformation": ""
          },
          {
            "roleid": 115,
            "rolename": "Staff",
            "divisionlabel": "Class",
            "subdivisionlabel": "Section",
            "roleinformation": {
              "1": [
                {
                  "A": 0
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "roleid": 116,
            "rolename": "Student",
            "divisionlabel": "Class",
            "subdivisionlabel": "Section",
            "roleinformation": {
              "1": [
                {
                  "A": 0
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "roleid": 184,
            "rolename": "CANt_MANAGE_Gbase",
            "divisionlabel": "Division",
            "subdivisionlabel": "SubDivision",
            "roleinformation": {
              "Div": [
                {
                  "Sdiv": 0
                },
                {
                  "Sdiv1": 0
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "roleid": 191,
            "rolename": "Legend",
            "divisionlabel": "a",
            "subdivisionlabel": "b"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
]

      $scope.ruleGrouped = [];
      angular.forEach(mData, function(assignedRule) {
        $scope.ruleGrouped.push(assignedRule.json.response.data.assignedroles);
        angular.forEach(assignedRule.json.response.data.unassignedroles, function(unassignedRule) {
            $scope.ruleGrouped.push(unassignedRule);
        });
      });
  }
]);
```

In HTML you need to modify your code as below

```
<select ng-model="form.selectedTestAccount" ng-options="rules.rolename for rules in ruleGrouped">

      <option value="" selected="selected">Choose</option>
  </select>
```